# Blocking onClick handler with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button with `onClick` event attached to it:

```
<button id="my-button" onClick={myMethod}>
   My button
</button>
```

I have also added an event listener to this button:

```
const listener = (e) => {
   // Do something here (or elsewhere) to prevent `myMethod` from being invoked
   console.log('Hello, world!');
}
const options = { capture: true, once: true };
document.getElementById('my-button')
   .addEventListener('click', listener, options);
```

Is it possible to add some method inside the `listener`, so the `myMethod` is stopped from being invoked?

Comment: have you tried `event.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: Is `myMethod` your code?

Comment: you should not mix react and plain js handlers. that just creates chaos.

Comment: How about just make it null ? `e.onclick = null;`

Comment: @AbSin - This is React, not HTML.

Comment: @Tony - `myMethod` is my code, some random method - here just for an example

Comment: @JonasWilms I know that. It's Sunday, some thing needs to be done quickly and I found this way to be the easiest - no time to jump into whole project's code :(

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! Can you suggest me something to read a bit more about why it wouldn't work is it because the DOM is virtual?

Comment: @AbSin - https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: @abSin Cause `onClick` is part of React `<button />`s props, it doesnt get reflected to the DOM.

Comment: @ancinek I guess that will cause more pain in the long term then just fixing it the right way once ... but thats not my authority, have fun monkey patching it :)

Comment: @JonasWilms I will jump into more reliable solution probably tomorrow, but T.J. Crowder 's answer will work for now :)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Combining React event handling and raw DOM event handling usually indicates a larger design issue. Having the one conflict with the other even more so. :-)

Having said that, React's event handlers use delegation, so the standard `e.stopPropagation` should do it:

```
const listener = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Hello, world!');
};
```

Example:

```js
function myMethod() {
    console.log("myMethod");
}
const Example = () => <button id="my-button" onClick={myMethod}>
    My button
</button>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

const listener = (e) => {
   // Do something here (or elsewhere) to prevent `myMethod` from being invoked
   e.stopPropagation();
   console.log('Hello, world!');
}
const options = { capture: true, once: true };
document.getElementById('my-button')
   .addEventListener('click', listener, options);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you'll need to re-attach your event handler **every time** React re-renders the component. This is part of why mixing these two systems is generally not your best approach.

Comment: @JonasWilms - I'm assuming (quite possibly incorrectly :-) ) that the OP is re-attaching the event listener when that happens. But very good point to raise.

Comment: Very good answer. Fortunately I'm attaching the listener in a way, that it is always there. Was not aware which event will be considered as the `top` one - the one inside the `onClick` prop, or the one added in the `addEvenetListener`. It clarifies things + some more React knowledge for this Sunday's afetrnoon :) Thanks!